# Symfony - Defining a route only in dev. environment

Tags: symfony, configuration, routes, yaml

I'm using SF2 and I created some routes helping the debugging of the project:

```cs
widget_debug_page:
    path:       /debug/widget/{widgetName}
    defaults:   { _controller: WidgetBundle:Debug:default }
```

The problem is that this route MUST never be reachable when going in production.

I could not find a parameter to specify the environment.

Answer (score 28):

Just for people who want use with `annotation` system:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/my-route", condition="'dev' === '%kernel.environment%'")
 */
public function index() {}
```

Comment: Symfony ExpressionLanguage component is required
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html

Answer (score 10):

You can add your route in `routing_dev.yml` (Symfony 2/3) or create a dev-only routing file in `config/routes/dev/` (Symfony 4).

Comment: Is it possible via annoations ? Maybe via the `condition` option (can't find documentation about it)

Comment: Doc for annotation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/conditions.html

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned perviously you can define the conditional route by adding 'condition' directive to the route definition. In case you need to limit the route for the appropriate environment you can check `%kernel.environment%` parameter value directly. For example:

```
widget_debug_page:
    path:       /debug/widget/{widgetName}
    defaults:   { _controller: WidgetBundle:Debug:default }
    condition:  "%kernel.environment% === 'dev'"
```

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar problem myself since I wanted to create a "System temporarily down due to maintenance"-page that would disable my site entirely in prod-environment only as I use dev-environment to make sure everything is alright after deploying an update to my production server. I guess its debatable whether this is good practice, but anyway...

The comment made by [Leto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894097/leto) to a previous answer gave me an idea how to solve it and I think I have successfully managed to make my route only work in dev-environment like so:

```
default_update_view:
    path:     /{route}
    defaults: { _controller: WalanderBundle:Default:maintenanceInfo }
    condition: "request.getScriptName() == '/app.php'"
    requirements:
        route: .+
```

No the question was to only enable a route in dev-environment which would then be done by changing the condition as follows if I'm not missing anything obvious:

```
condition: "request.getScriptName() == '/app_dev.php'"
```

Hope this helps although the question was a bit old!

Perhaps in the case when you want to enable a route in the dev-environment only the already provided answer by [JonaPkr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/484776/jonapkr) is best practice though.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony >= 5.3

```
when@dev:
    widget_debug_page:
    path:       /debug/widget/{widgetName}
    defaults:   { _controller: WidgetBundle:Debug:default }
```

reference: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-configure-multiple-environments-in-a-single-file