# Restrict Symfony 4 route to the "dev" environment

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4.1.  I'm trying to create a route "/dev/import/{file}" which can only be accessed from within the 'dev' environment.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253545/symfony-defining-a-route-only-in-dev-environment) for Symfony 2 suggests adding the route to `routing_dev.yml` or adding `condition: "request.getScriptName() == '/app_dev.php'"` to your route definition.

Neither option will work.  In Symfony 4 there is no `routing_dev.yml`, it's now `dev\routing_dev.YAML`, which as far as I can tell is configuration only (i.e. you can not create routes there).  Routes have to be defined in `routes.yaml` which will apply to all environments.

Adding the route to `routes.yaml` and applying the condition also does not work, as we're trying to match against the `app_dev` front controller, which has been removed in Symfony 4.

According to the [Symfony 4 Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/conditions.html), conditions in routes only expose the `Context` and `Request` objects, neither of which (AFAICT) contain any information about the current environment.  So, unless I am missing something, other conditions will not work either.

One possible, but (IMHO) inelegant solution would be to check that `$_SERVER['APP_ENV'] = 'dev'` in the controller and throw a `RouteNotFoundException` if it does not.

Rather than doing that, I would really like to either have the route simply not be available when not in 'dev', or define the route somehow to test for the 'dev' environment.

Any ideas on how to do that?  Preferably using annotations.

Comment: No idea how to do this using evil annotations but putting your routing file under config/routes/dev will work.  Not sure where it is documented but if you install the debug bundle then the directory is created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony disable controller actions in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439037/symfony-disable-controller-actions-in-production)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you see the default `configureRoutes()` method on the generated `Kernel` class:

```
 protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes)
    {
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';

        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
    }
```

The second `import()` call reads:

```
$routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
```

This will try to load routes defined under `config/routes/[environment]`.

So if you create a `dev` folder there and add your routes there, those will only be loaded when on that specific environment. Logically that could also be used to define specific, specialized routes for other possible environments, although generally that wouldn't very particularly useful.

Of course, the generated `configureRoutes()` method belongs to your app, and you are free to tweak it to your needs if they are more esoteric. You could always rewrite it so it loaded the routes you wanted in the specific order you of your preference.

---

Apparently, you can also use 'conditions' ([documented here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/conditions.html)) to define the same route but evaluate at runtime if it applies according to specific circumstances.:

E.g, as shown in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56712007/1426539) using annotations:

> ```
> /**
>  * @Route("/my_route", condition="'dev' === '%kernel.environment%'")
>  */
> ```

Or using YAML configuration, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49242319/1426539):

> ```
> my_route:
>     path:       /my_route}
>     defaults:   { _controller: App\Controller\MyRouteController }
>     condition:  "%kernel.environment% === 'dev'"
> ```

Or using XML configuration:

```xml
<!-- config/routes.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing
        https://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="my_route" path="/my_route" controller="App\Controller\MyRouteController">
        <condition>%kernel.environment% === 'dev'</condition>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Comment: This answer just helped me with this exact problem, thank you.
I used the YAML version. One thig I had to change compared to your answer is to surround %kernel.environment% with simple quotes (condition:  "'%kernel.environment%' === 'dev'")